# Can Link monsters be switched to defense?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

One thing I've noticed is that Link monsters don't even have defense points. A card I like to use is [Book of Moon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Moon), which lets me switch a monster into face-down defense mode. Since Link monsters don't even Def category, is it still possible to switch them into face-down or face-up defense?

Comment: Not to be rude but, did you even googled this before asking? That is what all the fuzz is about Links when they came up. Included an answer that quotes the official ruling and other reference for you to check if you want.

Comment: fair enough. I guess I should've already known that. no def category, how can they be switched to a category mode they don't even have.

Comment: Well, considering *all* the cards that set or change position (and even those Archetypes that strongly rely on such) it is actually a surprise that Link monsters can't, it's actually not intuitive. If I were Konami I would have made a better rule saying "Link monsters have 0 def"... and if someone moves it (therefore messing with the zones it points to) then I thing that would be a good strategy to counter links (but again, Konami doesn't want to counter them yet remember?)

Comment: Have you _even read the rulebook_?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Official Ruling](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/SD_RuleBook_EN_10.pdf), page 15, first paragraph:

> Link Monsters have no DEF and **cannot ever be in Defense Position**. 
>   They can’t be changed to Defense Position by a card effect. They 
>   can’t even be flipped into face-down Defense Position.

We can see that Link monsters can't ever be in Defense position, not face-up or face-down. This also excludes changes from card effects like [Book of Moon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Moon).

More info on [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/39919/22373) answer and question.

Comment: There was a card effect that allows you to switch one monster into face down attack mode. I can't remember what it was, but that would work right? Because it may not be able to be switched to defense mode, but it's only switched face down, but it's still in attack mode.

Comment: @Therationalduelist you mean [Darkness Approaches](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Approaches)? See [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34781/how-does-face-down-attack-position-via-darkness-approaches-work) question, and [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35377/was-darkness-approaches-erratad-in-the-ocg-because-of-link-monsters) one also. It's effect has been changed, now it flips to face down defense :( they killed the card IMO

Answer (score 0):

Link monsters cannot be in defense mode as they do not have any defense points, also changing to defense mode changes the zones they point to as the card orientation has changed.

Please see these links for more information.

http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Link_Monster

https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/61co6b/what_if_link_monsters_are_forced_to_change_to/

https://www.google.ch/search?q=link+monsters+defense+mode&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=OSl4WtCPNdD08Aft_YzQAw

Comment: Correct, this is the most significant detail of Link monsters perhaps.

Comment: We try to avoid link-only answers because of the links ever go dead, then it becomes worthless. Could you perhaps add a relevant quote from each of your sources?

Comment: Neither of those things prevents them being in defence mode. No listed DEF defaults to zero, and this would be a loophole allowing changes in zone as a tactical consideration. The **only** reason they can't be placed in defence mode is literally *the rules say they cannot*.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a card called Darkness Approaches which allows it to be face down either attack or defense relevant to the card's current position.

More on the rulings of:
[Darkness Approaches: Ruling](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Approaches)
Very useful to flip the Link monsters to face down attack position.  Hopefully, you can add these can of worms into your deck for maximum trolling.

Comment: Welcome to the site Gareth! You may want to remove the question that you added in your most recent edit. Stack Exchange is a bit different from a normal forum, answer are intended to answer the original question completely without really starting a discussion. You can [check out the tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) if you want to learn more about how the site works, and how to write great questions and answers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, wasnt aware that could hurt x.x

Comment: The card Darkness Approaches was errata'd, see [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35377/was-darkness-approaches-erratad-in-the-ocg-because-of-link-monsters) question for more info. It now does not place face down attack position, it "just" places face down defense position... it's even there in the link you shared...